# Deploy Dash with assets folder to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, plotly-dash

I was wondering if anyone would be able to advise me on how to upload a Dash app to elastic beanstalk.

I understand from various peoples blogs to ensure that I need:

```
application = app.server

if __name__ == '__main__':
application.run_server(debug=True,port=8080)
```

Then I need to freeze the requirements using pip freeze > requirements.txt and zip all the files and upload to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. In all the explanations they have very simple applications with only a single file and that have no "assets" folders containing css files or no connected databases

I was wondering what the process is when you have an assets folder containing various images and css folders of styles etc. I have also connected a RDS database already set up using the URI with sqlalchemy. The app works perfectly when it is on my local machine. I tried zipping every individual file but it has not worked and I am getting quite desperate. I understand that Dash looks for the "assets" folder. Structure found below:

[image]

Thank you very much for your help in advance. If anyone could highlight the exact steps I need to do I would very much appreciate it. I am very new to this.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried zip the entire project folder and upload to Elastic Beanstalk? Best way to do is get into the project folder and select all files using Ctrl+A and Right Click and Archive it. Make sure it has the .zip extension

Answer (score 3):

I had an identical problem, and here's how I solved it. By default, Dash automatically serves all of the files included in the `./assets` folder. Oppositely a webserver on AWS Elastic Beanstalk expects your CSS and other files to be placed in the `./static` folder.

You may create a configuration file for AWS Elastic Beanstalk to set configuration options for your static files. I took another approach:

1. Change your resources' folder name from **assets** to **static**.
2. Update your Python code when you declare Dash app:

   ```
    app = dash.Dash(name=__name__,
                    title="My App",
                    assets_folder ="static",
                    assets_url_path="static")
   ```
3. Deploy your app as usual - AWS Elastic Beanstalk will take resources and serve them from the **static** folder.

My final app has the following structure:

```
static/
  favicon.ico
  logo.png
  style.css
application.py  # by default, AWS Elastic Beanstalk expects this app name
requirements.txt
```

#### References

- [Adding Your Own CSS and JavaScript to Dash Apps](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources).
- [Using the Elastic Beanstalk Python platform with static files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html#python-platform-staticfiles).